# Movie about a girl with multiple personality disorder

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

The movie starts with a father picking up his daughter from a mental asylum, and returning to their home situated near a river. The film focuses on four characters mainly, father, a step-mother, sister and the main protagonist. Her mother died long before and she used to cry before the photo.

> The climax is, she kills the step-mother along with her younger sister, and confesses to her father. Then her father tells her that her sister died a year ago. Then she realizes that it was an illusion. She killed the step-mother herself and the movie ends on taking her back to the mental asylum.

English Hollywood Movie. I assume the release date might be between 2005-2012.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [The Uninvited](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0815245/combined) with Emily Browning and Elizabeth Banks from 2009.

> After the death of her ill mother in a fire, the young teenager Anna tries to commit suicide and is sent to a mental institution for treatment. Ten months later, Anna still cannot remember what had happened on the night her mother died. Her psychiatric Dr. Silberling, however, discharges her telling that she has resolved her issues. Her father and successful writer, Steven, brings her back home in an isolated mansion nearby the coast. Anna finds that her mother's former nurse, Rachel Summers, is her stepmother now. Anna meets her beloved sister, Alex, swimming in the sea. She discovers that Steven has not delivered the letters and CDs that Alex had sent to her. As time moves on, Anna is haunted by ghosts and she believes that Rachel killed her mother. Alex and Anna decide to look for evidences to prove that Rachel is the murderer and Anna discovers the truth about the fire in the boat house.

Anna ends up killing her stepmother. Her sister was dead all along. Here's the trailer: